# java.io.IOException: No LZO codec found, cannot run

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, lzo

I tried to use lzo in my hive script, but got this error message. It seemed that I did not have the class for lzo in the classpath.

Did anyone else meet this problem before, how to fix this problem, maybe what I need to know is that where I can get the jar file for the lzo compression, thx.

Comment: Is this applicable? [HIVE-2395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2395)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/) are some detailed instructions on how to setup LZO compression.

Answer (score 0):

Lzo configuration is not correct in one (or all) of the nodes.

Add the following configuration in core-site.xml.

```
<property> 
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name> 
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name> 
  <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value> 
</property>
```